# R regex replace & vector

Tags: r, regex, stringr

How does one do `str_replace` with a "starting with" `^` and a vector?

I am trying to remove the prefixes (Mr., Ms., Dr., Capt., etc.) from a list of names, only from the beginning. I have tried: `str_replace(name, prefix, '')`. This replaces only a few of the prefixes (Mr., Ms., Dr., Capt., etc.) from the vector of names but most prefixes are still present. At the same time I don't want to replace the Dr in say `Dr. Drake` to `ake`. `Dr. Drake` should be `Drake`.

```
name <- c('Mrs. Emily S', 'Dr. Richard L', 'Dr. Drake D', 'Mr. Mrdrmsmrs', 'Test Name')
prefix <- c('Dr.', 'Mr.', 'Ms.', 'Mrs.', 'Capt.')
# Wiktor Stribiżew's code
str_replace(name, paste0("^(?:", paste(prefix, collapse="|"), ")(?!\\.)"), '')
```

There are whitespaces. However we can remove those with `trimws()` or `stringr::str_trim()`

Comment: Can you include multiple string samples in your question and what the expected outcomes should be? It's unclear what you're asking without this (e.g. is `Dr. Drake` supposed to be `Dr. Drake` or `Drake`?). Also, what have you tried? Please [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: If your `prefix` is something like `c("Dr", "Ms", "Mr")` you may try `str_replace(name, paste0("^(?:",paste(prefix, collapse="|"), ")(?!\\.)"), '')`

Comment: @ctwheels The result should be `Drake`. Updated the description. Sorry about that.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Looks like it worked! Thank you so much!!! How can I give you reputation?

Comment: @Highland can you post other string samples to test against as well?

Comment: @ctwheels Added to the question.

Comment: Please see the answer adjusted to the data you added to the question. Note that I added `sort.by.length.desc` related stuff just in case there is a more generic issue when you have overlapping items in the prefix character vector and when you cannot rely on any boundaries be it a `\b` word boundary or `.`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to remove alphanumeric strings defined in your `prefix` character vector only when they appear at the start of the string. They contain a literal `.` that must be escaped to denote the literal `.` in the pattern.

Use

```
regex.escape <- function(string) {
  gsub("([][{}()+*^${|\\\\?.])", "\\\\\\1", string)
}
sort.by.length.desc <- function (v) v[order( -nchar(v)) ]  ## Just in case you have overlapping items in prefix char vector

name <- c('Mrs. Emily S', 'Dr. Richard L', 'Dr. Drake D', 'Mr. Mrdrmsmrs', 'Test Name')
prefix <- c('Dr.', 'Mr.', 'Ms.', 'Mrs.', 'Capt.')
prefix <- sort.by.length.desc(prefix) ## This is not important unless any abbreviation ends with more than 1 dot, else you may remove this line for the current problem
res <- trimws(gsub(paste0("^(?:",paste(regex.escape(prefix), collapse="|"), ")"), '', name, perl="TRUE"))
res
## => [1] "Emily S"   "Richard L" "Drake D"   "Mrdrmsmrs" "Test Name"
## OR
## res <- trimws(str_replace(name, paste0("^(?:",paste(regex.escape(prefix), collapse="|"), ")"), ''))
```

See the [online R demo](https://ideone.com/UhaiFv).

Here, `paste0("^(?:",paste(regex.escape(prefix), collapse="|"), ")")` dynamically creates a pattern like `^(?:Mr\.|Ms\.|Dr\.|Capt\.)` that matches strings like this:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:Mr\.|Ms\.|Dr\.|Capt\.)` - `Mr.`, `Ms.`, `Dr.`, `Capt.`, etc.

Comment: What's the purpose of the 4 and 6 backslashes, to escape other backslahes? The first `str_replace(name, paste0("^(?:", paste(prefix, collapse="|"), ")(?!\\.)"), '')` seems to work fine. Is the updated more robust?

Comment: @Highland The point is that `(?!\.)` negative lookahead was pointless. You have `Dr.` in the `prefix`. If you use `Dr.` in the regex pattern, it will match `Dr<space>`, `DrD` (in `DrDrake`, etc. because a `.` matches any char (but a line break char in PCRE/ICU regex flavors). So, you need 1) `regex.escape`, 2) if you have `Mr.` and `Mr..` and the first appears before the second, the second `.` will remain because the first alternative inside the alternation group (`(...|...|....)`) that matches "wins" and the rest of the alternatives are not even tried. Hence, `sort.by.length.desc` is used.

Comment: Let's say there were suffixes in the name. Seems like adjusting the last line to `trimws(gsub(paste0("(?:",paste(regex.escape(prefix), collapse="|"), ")$"), '', name, perl="TRUE"))` works. Is that a proper method?

Comment: @Highland Yes, [it is good](https://regex101.com/r/OW08Cy/1). It will remove the substrings at the end of the string. Make sure you either add `\\b` before `(?:` or sort as I showed, by length in the descending order.